# ¿Alguien sabe qué código es este? - Seguridad en imágenes

Tags: wordpress-imagenes

Yo antes usaba programas para scrapear, crawl, o veía código fuente para descargar cómics sea japonés, coreano o chino para guardarlas. Sin embargo, antes no me interesaba mucho y lo descargaba y ya, ya que la mayoría de páginas no tenían sistemas para estos. Pero, hace un par de años había entrado a cierta página China, en aquella vez me arruinó algunas entradas, lo cual tuve que reemplazar nuevamente, y veté a la página porque no podía obtener la imagen, como había varias era fácil reemplazarla, pero en esos tiempos le saqué capture por si acaso. Pero hoy en día, tengo mi propia página web y saco proyectos; y pues empezaron a quitarme contenido. Y justo me había acordado de dicha página; pregunté a un programador sobre esta imagen (como se visualiza en el reader, se ve bien pero cuando se hace el proceso para descargar, la imagen ya está arruinada sea crawl, scrap y/o f12 en esos tiempos):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero el amigo no sabía mucho, y siento la necesidad de integrar ese sistema a mi página web para proteger el contenido. Obviamente, desconozco si la página sigue viva, ya que éstas tienen las particularidades de cambiar de dominio.
Como vi que los chinos lo hicieron, solo preguntaba. ¿Qué lenguaje de programación sería? Desconozco mucho de programación, solo soy un aficionado.
Entiendo que todo lo que se sube en web, se puede "robar" o "descargar". Sin embargo, que lo descargue pero arruinado.
Lamento mi biblia. :( Espero leer sus experiencias, y/o comentarios.

Comment: Tiene pinta de ser algo que luego javascript recoloca de algun modo. Consiguiendo su javascript podrias entenderlo mejor. Pero para mi no tiene sentido intentar proteger imágenes pues con una simple captura de pantalla ya las consiguen, o una foto si me apuras :-). Las respuestas a esta pregunta estarán basadas en opiniones, como la mia, ademas carece de código y de error, y es probable que sea cerrada pronto, lo siento. El único sentido de protegerlas es que no las usen desde otros sitios webs y mantengan la referencia a tu servidor, pagando tu su hosting y transferencia.

Comment: Gracias por responder, sucede que en este tipo de negocio. Raras veces suben como captura de pantalla o el sistema de ópera; y la gran mayoría usan scrap, crawl y/o programas para bajar tipo "hakuneko" o f12. Entendería el robo si fuera unas 200 imágenes, pero en este rubro se publican más de 30, 000 imágenes, así que manual no es una opción para los que roban contenido, y más van por crawl o scrap. Aún así, gracias por responder. ☺️